# Using a "Shadow DOM" today?

Tags: html, shadow-dom

I'm pretty lost on all the Shadow DOM and Web Components stuff so forgive me...

I think the idea of Shadow DOM is just to have all the data in your app live inside a datastructure whose API works exactly like the traditional DOM. Correct?

The purpose being simply to make shucking around data, processing data, filing and querying data, easier for most people by providing a de facto standard way of doing it that happens to use an API that everyone already knows by heart. Correct?

If so, is there any way (a library?) that I can start getting my feet wet with this way of doing things, right now?

Answer (score 3):

In addition, I found this on the subject from [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/):

- A document tree is a node tree [DOM] whose root node is a document.
- Any element can host zero or one associated node trees, called a shadow tree.
- A shadow root is the root node of a shadow tree.
- A component tree is either a document tree or a shadow tree.

So based on what I've just shown, the best explanation I've found is this from [What the Heck is Shadow DOM?](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) shown below:

> Shadow DOM refers to the ability of the browser to include a subtree
>   of DOM elements into the rendering of a document, but not into the
>   main document DOM tree.

An important use case would be with video controls on a web page.  The markup only shows a video tag, with some attributes and source tags.  The addtional code for all the video operations to work is hidden in the Shadow DOM and not available to the rest of the page.  The actual markup, javascript, and styles for the `<video>` tag are encapsulated, which hides the implementation details of the video controls that each browser vendor has already written.

So while it's there in the DOM, its hidden from the page that renders it.  So, to view the Shadow DOM, you can enable it under Dev Tools in Chrome.
[image]

Then you can view it as shown below:
[image]

The short answer is that the Shadow DOM is one of four technologies that make up Web Components.  That is it's relationship with Web Components in general.

For a definition, Web Components are:  A component platform from the W3C that allows Web sites to be constructed from standardized building blocks. Web Components comprise Custom Elements, Shadow DOM and HTML Imports and Templates.

So while Shadow DOM is a technology of Web Components, see [MDN's page on Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) consists of these four technologies (although each can be used separately):

1. **Custom Elements**: is a capability for creating your own custom HTML tags and elements. They can have their own scripted behavior and CSS styling. They are part of Web Components but they can also be used by themselves.
2. **HTML Templates**: The HTML template element `<template>` is a mechanism for holding client-side content that is not to be rendered when a page is loaded but may subsequently be instantiated during runtime using JavaScript. Think of a template as a content fragment that is being stored for subsequent use in the document.
3. **Shadow DOM**: provides encapsulation for the JavaScript, CSS, and templating in a Web Component.  Shadow DOM makes it so these things remain separate from the DOM of the main document. You can also use Shadow DOM by itself, outside of a web component.
4. **HTML Imports**: is intended to be the packaging mechanism for Web Components, but you can also use HTML Imports by itself.  You import an HTML file by using a `<link>` tag in an HTML document.

Here are three Web Components libraries:

- Polymer (uses all four technologies),
- X-Tag (only uses Custom Elements),
- and Bosonic(only uses Custom Elements, which calls itself a library of low-level UI elements).

I also found this site which may be of interest: [Web Components.org](http://webcomponents.org/) A place to discuss and evolve Web Component best-practices

Answer (score 2):

That's definitely one of the purposes of Web Components (wrap your entire app in an encapsulated, reusable DOM element), and you're perfectly justified in using it that way only. The ideal use, however, would extend all the way down into the app. Any part of your app that you could conceivably make into a reusable "widget" could also benefit from Shadow DOM encapsulation. Imagine an app developed by a team of 50 people where there are specific boundaries and well-defined APIs between components. There would be very little of the CSS clashing, hard-to-read code, and tight coupling that most web apps anywhere near that size have today.

As far as using these cutting-edge technologies today, check out the open-source [Polymer Project](http://www.polymer-project.org/) from Google. It includes a set of polyfills that bring Web Components and all the related technologies to every modern browser, as well as some syntactic sugaring that make working with this stuff much more enjoyable.